# Hand Cursor for Label vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm developing an application with many controls. I want to change the mouse cursor when it passes over a Label. I took a look in the option but there you have a limited choice and not what I want. I tried also to upload a mouse icon but I faced two difficulties: the first one is finding an icon under license `cc0` and the second one is that Excel doesn't accept the format that I found. Can you please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're on Windows, it will require a .cur file or .ani (animated cursor) file type.  You can find a list of native Windows cursor images in C:\Windows\Cursors, there are a few hand ones so hopefully one of those will be close to what you're looking for.  If not, you can browse what others have created at a cursor sharing site like [Cursor Library](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-library/set-0) or create your own using something like [Cursor Editor](https://www.cursor.cc/)

Comment: thanks @tigeravatar but are they free for use without attribution ? I'm indeed under Windows 10

Comment: For the Cursor Library, here's a link to their [licensing page](http://www.rw-designer.com/licenses).  Basically when you click to get more information about a cursor you can see what license is was published under.  Most will be `Released to Public Domain` or a type of `Creative Commons`.  For the cursors you create yourself using the Cursor Editor, that's free to use without attribution, and you can choose to publish any cursor you create under the Creative Commons license.

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar i tried but vba excel doesn't accept .ani extension ...

Comment: If possible, I highly recommend sticking with a .cur file.  Animated cursor files would need to be loaded as their own object in Excel VBA and then referenced from there, much more complicated and prone to making your life and your users' lives harder.  If it must be a .ani file, see [this thread](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/70222-animated-cursor.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Windows API to change the cursor appearance. I'm assuming this is in an Excel UserForm, so you can use the `MouseMove` event to know when the mouse is over the label.

Here's the code that you would add in the code behind in a form.

```
Option Explicit

'Api Declarations
Private Declare Function GetCursorInfo Lib "user32" (ByRef pci As CursorInfo) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadCursor Lib "user32" Alias "LoadCursorA" (ByVal hInstance As Long, ByVal lpCursorName As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursor Lib "user32" (ByVal hCursor As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

'You can use the default cursors in windows
Public Enum CursorTypes
    IDC_ARROW = 32512
    IDC_IBEAM = 32513
    IDC_WAIT = 32514
    IDC_CROSS = 32515
    IDC_UPARROW = 32516
    IDC_SIZE = 32640
    IDC_ICON = 32641
    IDC_SIZENWSE = 32642
    IDC_SIZENESW = 32643
    IDC_SIZEWE = 32644
    IDC_SIZENS = 32645
    IDC_SIZEALL = 32646
    IDC_NO = 32648
    IDC_HAND = 32649
    IDC_APPSTARTING = 32650
End Enum

'Needed for GetCursorInfo
Private Type POINT
    X As Long
    Y As Long
End Type

'Needed for GetCursorInfo
Private Type CursorInfo
    cbSize As Long
    flags As Long
    hCursor As Long
    ptScreenPos As POINT
End Type

'Event that handles knowing when the mouse is over the control
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    AddCursor IDC_HAND
End Sub

'To set a cursor
Private Function AddCursor(CursorType As CursorTypes)
    If Not IsCursorType(CursorType) Then
        SetCursor LoadCursor(0, CursorType)
        Sleep 200 ' wait a bit, needed for rendering
    End If
End Function

'To determine if the cursor is already set
Private Function IsCursorType(CursorType As CursorTypes) As Boolean
    Dim CursorHandle As Long: CursorHandle = LoadCursor(ByVal 0&, CursorType)
    Dim Cursor As CursorInfo: Cursor.cbSize = Len(Cursor)
    Dim CursorInfo As Boolean: CursorInfo = GetCursorInfo(Cursor)

    If Not CursorInfo Then
        IsCursorType = False
        Exit Function
    End If

    IsCursorType = (Cursor.hCursor = CursorHandle)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan , I don't understand your code but it works :p many thanks

Comment: This is almost there but I see the cursor flickering as you move the mouse over the label. It looks like this might be the reason:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor

"If your application must set the cursor while it is in a window, make sure the class cursor for the specified window's class is set to NULL. If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor each time the mouse is moved."